# Is there a "partition uuid" for a logical volume?

Tags: partition, lvm, kickstart

I'm doing a kickstart installation. On the kernel boot line, the kickstart file is specified by `inst.ks=hd:LABEL=<lv label>:/ks.cfg`. The kernel/anaconda finds and loads this. In the kickstart script, though, I need to specify a `partition` where the os root that anaconda can boot from. But if the os root is on a lv, then what is the partition needed (ie, for the harddrive kickstart command)?

TIA

ken

Answer (score 0):

There are UUIDs for LVs, too. I am not familiar with kickstart but perhaps you can just use them:

```
$ lvdisplay linux0/rootfs | grep UUID
  LV UUID                iU1gdu-X9GM-xcgw-gHTe-yeBq-BlkV-SRgVn8
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - I did try. I looked in `/dev/disk/by-partid`, and all partitions on non-lv disks were there. thx, tho.

Comment: @daytooner I did not mean that the LVM UUID appears there. That is not the purpose of `/dev/disk` anyway. I meant there is an LVM-specific kind of UUID. Software which shall use that has to be LVM-aware.